# How to extract object from another object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this array object, and I'm trying to create another object out of it. I already have a solution but I think there may be a shorter way of doing what I'm doing. Does anyone know how to make this code shorter or another way using lodash or pure javascript? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
{
 firstName: Mike,
 lastName : Brown
}
```

so far my code works and looks like this:

```js
let response =     [
     {
  "Name": "hobby",
  "Value": "poker"
    }, 
    {
  "Name": "privacy_id",
  "Value": "1112"
    }, {
  "Name": "given_name",
  "Value": "Mike"
    }, 
    {
  "Name": "family_name",
  "Value": "Brown"
    }, 
    {
  "Name": "email",
  "Value": "test@email.com"
    }
 ]
 
 const newObj = {};
 _.forEach(response, function(obj) {
       if(obj.Name === 'given_name') { newObj.firstName = obj.Value}
       if(obj.Name === 'family_name'){ newObj.lastName = obj.Value}
  });
  
  console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Challange accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good usecase for [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) since what you want is to transform an array into something - something being an object in your case:

```
const newObj = response.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.Name] = curr.Value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

This would transform:

```
const response = [
  {
    'Name': 'given_name',
    'Value': 'Mike'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'family_name',
    'Value': 'Brown'
  }
]
```

into:

```
{
  'given_name': 'Mike',
  'family_name': 'Brown'
}
```

Now, if you want to change the naming of the key, you could use some sort of mapping:

```
const NameMapping = {
  given_name: 'firstName',
  family_name: 'lastName'
};

const response = [
  {
    'Name': 'given_name',
    'Value': 'Mike'
  },
  {
    'Name': 'family_name',
    'Value': 'Brown'
  }
]

const newObj = response.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (NameMapping[curr.Name] === undefined)
    return acc;

  acc[NameMapping[curr.Name]] = curr.Value;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

So your `newObj` would look like this:

```
{
  firstName: 'Mike',
  familyName: 'Brown'
}
```

Comment: Can you share a live demo please? It doesn't seem to work

Comment: Thanks a lot bro!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that `response` contains both the object with the key `given_name` and the object with the key `family_name`, you could write this way:

```
const newObj = {
    'given_name': response.filter(el => el.Name ==='given_name')[0].Value,
    'family_name': response.filter(el => el.Name ==='family_name')[0].Value,
}
```

There's the fiddle:

```js
let response =     [
     {
  "Name": "hobby",
  "Value": "poker"
    }, 
    {
  "Name": "privacy_id",
  "Value": "1112"
    }, {
  "Name": "given_name",
  "Value": "Mike"
    }, 
    {
  "Name": "family_name",
  "Value": "Brown"
    }, 
    {
  "Name": "email",
  "Value": "test@email.com"
    }
 ]
 
 const newObj = {
    'given_name': response.filter(el => el.Name ==='given_name')[0].Value,
    'family_name': response.filter(el => el.Name ==='family_name')[0].Value,
 }
  
 console.log(newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```